# .htaccess rewrite for all but robots.txt and sitemap.xml

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple PHP MVC architecture that routes all requests through a public/index.php.  I am using .htaccess to route all requests and also to enforce "wwww" and "https" but I cannot figure out how exclude robots.txt and sitemap.xml.  Here is what I currently have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would greatly appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule ^((?!robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml).*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

the pattern above **((?!robots.txt|sitemap.xml).*)** matches any request excluding **/robots.txt** and **/sitemap.xml** .

Comment: You are a hero!  Three supposed "Apache experts" couldn't get this to work.  Cheers!!!